# Solidity - ERC1155 NFT minting - Gas estimation failed: execution reverted

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, nft

This is my first attempt at minting NFT's. I am using ERC1155 contract to mint a full collection. Getting the following error when trying to deploy:

```
Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
execution reverted
```

Using the following code:

```
pragma solidity 0.8.0;

import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC1155/ERC1155.sol";
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/utils/math/SafeMath.sol";

contract NFT is ERC1155 {
    using SafeMath for uint256;
    
    constructor() ERC1155("ipfs://[IPFS_HASH]/{id}.json") {
        _mint(msg.sender, 0, 1, "");
        _mint(msg.sender, 1, 1, "");
        _mint(msg.sender, 2, 1, "");
        _mint(msg.sender, 3, 1, "");   
        // ... The above line repeats 3,686 more times with the ID incrementing accordingly
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How do you repeat the line 3700 times? Copy-pasted or in a `for` loop with the same values? Or different values each time? If different - which ones are different and which ones stay the same?

Comment: @PetrHejda I created a script to generate the 3700 lines to a txt file then copy pasted the contents of the file.

Comment: Ok. And the values passed to the `_mint()` function, are always `msg.sender, 0, 1, ""`? Or did the script generate different values for each of the lines?

Comment: @PetrHejda script generated values for each line. Basically the second argument increments by 1 for each line.